# Dramatically increasing voltage in a circuit

Tags: voltage

Suppose I have a small AC generator, which produces an unstable current at 1 volt. How can I transform this into 10000 volts, decreasing the amperage accordingly? It does not matter if the output is AC or DC, nor does it matter if the output is stable.

Is there a small, inexpensive way to do this in a circuit, rather than having a huge transformer box?

Comment: A small transformer box?

Comment: One most know the input power range and load to see if there is adequate supply.

Comment: Is it possible to make a transformer small enough to fit in a circuit board that does this? Wouldn't a massive amount of wire be required, making it bulky?

Comment: Welcome. It is not practical to wind your own LF transformer. The secondary goes on first, and it would have thousands of turns. Consider an old neon light transformer. They step up by a factor of 100 or so. Not many things work well at 1 VAC.

Comment: What frequency is this 1VAC? If it's high enough, it might be possible to use a small transformer to step it up to a point where you have enough to work with to actually drive some kind of charge pump. You might find it more practical to directly generate the high voltage using something like a Wimshurst machine.

Comment: it it was producing 3V you could use a stun-gun energizer module. $5 or so

Answer (score 0):

The current source must ideally be stored into a battery cell with 0.8V  or a suitable Cap before it is converted and kept about 0.8V within a 10% tolerance for acceptable MPT using half bridge.  This is how MPPT converters store energy.

If you use a transformer, the load impedance requires 5 to 10% of max current to couple energy to the secondary. Thus when you determine these parameters for max source energy, and equivalent source impedance who can decide if there is a suitable reactance to upconvert or use sub-threshold CMOS to transfer current with 0.8V Vgs and a suitable high inductance flyback coil.